# python map each word to its own text

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have a list of words like this:

```
 word_list=[{"word": "python",
    "repeted": 4},
    {"word": "awsome",
    "repeted": 3},
    {"word": "frameworks",
    "repeted": 2},
    {"word": "programing",
    "repeted": 2},
    {"word": "stackoverflow",
    "repeted": 2},
    {"word": "work",
    "repeted": 1},
    {"word": "error",
    "repeted": 1},
    {"word": "teach",
    "repeted": 1}
    ]
```

,that comes from another list of notes:

```
note_list = [{"note_id":1,
"note_txt":"A curated list of awesome Python frameworks"},
{"note_id":2,
"note_txt":"what is awesome Python frameworks"},
{"note_id":3,
"note_txt":"awesome Python is good to wok with it"},
{"note_id":4,
"note_txt":"use stackoverflow to lern programing with python is awsome"},
{"note_id":5,
"note_txt":"error in programing is good to learn"},
{"note_id":6,
"note_txt":"stackoverflow is very useful to share our knoloedge"},
{"note_id":7,
"note_txt":"teach, work"},
  ]
```

I want to know how can I map every word to its own note:

```
maped_list=[{"word": "python",
        "notes_ids": [1,2,3,4]},
        {"word": "awsome",
        "notes_ids": [1,2,3]},
        {"word": "frameworks",
        "notes_ids": [1,2]},
        {"word": "programing",
        "notes_ids": [4,5]},
        {"word": "stackoverflow",
        "notes_ids": [4,6]},
        {"word": "work",
        "notes_ids": [7]},
        {"word": "error",
        "notes_ids": [5]},
        {"word": "teach",
        "notes_ids": [7]}
        ]
```

my work:

```
# i started by appending all the notes text into one list
notes_test = []
for note in note_list:
notes_test.append(note['note_txt'])
# calculate the reptition of each word
dict = {}
for sentence in notes_test:
    for word in re.split('\s', sentence): # split with whitespace
        try:
            dict[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dict[word] = 1
word_list= []
for key in dict.keys():
    word = {}
    word['word'] = key
    word['repeted'] = dict[key]
    word_list.append(word)
```

my question:

1. how can I map the word list and note list to get the mapped list
2. how do you find the quality of my code, any remarks

Comment: The way you have asked this question is very confusing. What I think you're trying to ask is: "I have a list of notes, I need to calculate the frequency of each word, and a list of the notes it's found in". Is that correct?

Comment: yes something like that, i already managed to calculate the frequency, but i confused on the list of notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
mapped_list = [{"word": w_dict["word"],
                "notes_ids": [n_dict["note_id"] for n_dict in note_list
                              if w_dict["word"].lower() in n_dict["note_txt"].lower()]
                } for w_dict in word_list]
```

The result would be:

```
[{'word': 'python', 'notes_ids': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
 {'word': 'awsome', 'notes_ids': [4]},
 {'word': 'frameworks', 'notes_ids': [1, 2]},
 {'word': 'programing', 'notes_ids': [4, 5]},
 {'word': 'stackoverflow', 'notes_ids': [4, 6]},
 {'word': 'work', 'notes_ids': [1, 2, 7]},
 {'word': 'error', 'notes_ids': [5]},
 {'word': 'teach', 'notes_ids': [7]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to create the maped_list while creating the dict, adding the index of a word when it's iterating.
2. Do not use `dict` as variable, it's a python's reserved name to create dicts, like `dict()`, if you use it, it will be overwritten. Also, yuor input don't contain any other white spaces other than space, you can use sentence.split(). Other thing you can do is transform all words in lowercase, so they don't differ if write uppercase or not.

Comment: thank you for answer, for number 2 yes i well , but i couldn't get the first remark

Comment: Try to create a blank maped_list before the loop. When you add the word to the dict, add it to the maped_list too. Like, you are in the note id 2, the first word will be 'what', after you add it to the dict, add it to the maped_list too and then append the note_id to the note_ids tag. If my answer helped you, please give me a vote up, I'm trying to increase my reputation.